# How can I send key chords to text area with Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I would like to simulate a user pressing shift-enter in a text area. Here is the code I am working with:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://pagewithtextarea");
var textarea = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myTextArea"));
//Send text
textarea.SendKeys("hello world!");
```

If I want to simulate pressing the enter button I can say:

```
textarea.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

How could I simulate pressing shift and enter at the same time?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simpler than I expected. Since SendKeys takes a string, and the static constants on Keys are all strings they can simply be concatenated together like this:

```
textarea.SendKeys(Keys.Shift + Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: Glad this worked for you.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me in IE9 or Chrome: `.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "A");`   Any suggestions?

Comment: I've had limited success getting Selenium to work at all in IE. I would look into your browser security settings to see if there is something preventing Selenium from fully controlling the browser.

Comment: @BrettVeenstra, try to use `.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");` instead of `.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "A");`

Comment: Try `webElement.SendKeys(Keys.LeftControl + "a");`

Comment: Does not work with me in FF 120 pressing Ctrl + shift + a

Answer (score 1):

for me, on c# only this variation works:

```
actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control);
actions.SendKeys("a");
actions.KeyUp(Keys.Control);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's something that you might do over and over, it may be worth making an extension method for it.  I did this since `.Clear()` doesn't work in our web app for some reason.  Instead of always sending a `CTRL+A` and `\b`, I just extended it with this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Blank(this IWebElement _el)
    {
        _el.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
        _el.SendKeys("\b");
    }
}
```

Then I just call `dynEl.Blank();` and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I modified it to return the element in order to chain the commands together. [element].ClearField().SendKeys("Title")

Answer (score 0):

Here's how keys.chord() is implemented in JavaScript:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d8ddb4d83972df0f565ef65264bcb733e7a94584/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/input.js#L135

which is already pretty close to the top accepted answer, I think the only difference is the Null character added to the end.  You could probably make a helper method to help you remember it, but unfortunately `OpenQA.Selenium.Keys` is a static class and all of it's properties return strings.  So if you wanted to do a nice wrapper around it you'd probably also have to wrap the keys class too.

Answer (score -3):

In Java, We have `chord` method, this method will send sequence of keys together:

```
textArea.SendKeys( Keys.chord(Keys.Control , "a" ) );
```

or

```
textArea.SendKeys( Keys.chord ( Keys.Shift,Keys.Enter ) );
```