# Sending Ctrl-0 to IE 9 in webdriver C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I attempting to send a Ctrl + 0 to set IE 9 to 100%.

I have tried the following snippets of code:

```
IWebElement query = Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));

query.SendKeys("^0");
query.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.NumberPad0);
```

I have also tried the actions object code:

```
 Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
 action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("0").KeyUp(Keys.Control).Perform();
```

I have read that in Java, WebDriver supports Keys.chord()
But I cannot find an implementation of this in C#.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: See [This][1] post. It looks similar to what you are trying to do.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766364/how-can-i-send-key-chords-to-text-area-with-selenium

Comment: Thanks Tony,  But the example is for Firefox and some replies indicate that it does not work on IE 9 which is what I am running into.

Comment: just for reference, `ctrl-0` in *IE 11.0.2* appears to have `ctrl-0` be 125% zoom =/

Answer (score 1):

The `<html>` tag will never be "visible" to the driver, thus can't have keys sent to it. The following code works for me:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "0");
```

However, with the most recent versions of the IEDriverServer.exe, you will not be able to get this far unless you set a special option for the driver to disable detection of the zoom setting. If your zoom level is not set to 100%, the `InternetExplorerDriver` constructor will throw an exception unless you instantiate your driver with something like:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Comment: Jim,  I have set the IgnoreZoomLevel to true,  But the SendKeys() still does not change the zoom level.  Since zoom level is ignored do I still need to change the zoom level?

Comment: Setting IgnoreZoomLevel will get you by the exception, but you will need to change the zoom level to 100% if you expect clicking on elements to work properly. Note that in my code example above, I am finding the `<body>` element, not the `<html>` element. Also, note that the syntax of the SendKeys() string uses a literal "0", not `Keys.NumberPad0`, which is critical to it working.

Comment: Jim, I have downloaded the latest webdriver and IEDriverServer.exe,  set the By.Tagname("body") and have tried (Keys.Control + "0") and still cannot change the zoom level.  Any thoughts?