# How to send SendKeys(Keys.Control + "p") will work in c# using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, selenium-chromedriver

Below Piece of code not working

```
Actions act = new Actions(Driver);
act.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "p").Build().Perform();
```

Trying to save page as PDF.

Comment: Well, `ctrl+p` is used for printing...

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Keys.Chord()` method like below:

```
Actions act = new Actions(Driver);
act.SendKeys(Keys.Chord(Keys.Control, "p")).Build().Perform();
```

A little `C#` syntax may need to change.

Comment: unable to use "Keys.Chord" ?
Is that need some namespace or packages ?

Comment: There's no Keys.Chord in C#. Instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766364/how-can-i-send-key-chords-to-text-area-with-selenium